# Android - Intent putExtra takes nullpointer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, null-pointer

I have a problem in android. In my program there is an activity that contains 4 fragment in a viewpager. From one of the fragments, I want to call a dialog activity, and also send a variable. This is my code:

```
 Intent popup = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
 PopUpWifi.class); popup.putExtra("WiFiID", String.valueOf(name));
 startActivity(popup);
```

Here is the code on the popup acitivity:

```
public class PopUpWifi extends Activity { 
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.popupwifi);

         TextView TVWifi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVWifi);
         EditText ETJelszo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETJelszo);

         String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("WiFiID");
         TVWifi.setText(value);
     } }
```

Here is the pupupwifi.xml:

```
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Wi-fi hálózat neve"
       android:textSize="@dimen/NewSize" />
   <TextView
       android:name="@+id/TVWifi"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Wi-fi"
       android:textSize="@dimen/NewSize" />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Kérem adja meg a jelszót:"
       android:textSize="@dimen/NewSize" />
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/ETJelszo"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="@dimen/NewSize" />
   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Bevitel"
       android:textSize="@dimen/NewSize" /> 
   </LinearLayout>
```

But I can try anything, it throws a nullpointer exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sss.home/com.sss.home.PopUpWifi}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sss.home.PopUpWifi.onCreate(PopUpWifi.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Probably `TVWifi` is not assigned to a view. Or it lays in a different layout than the one specified in `setContentView()`

Comment: Have you checked what exactly throws the NPE? Maybe the `TextView` is null?

Comment: where are writing TVWifi.setText(value);

Comment: can you post send PopUpWifi.java class onCreate method?

Comment: I refreshed my question.

Comment: can you post R.layout.popupwifi? I don't think the problem is with the intent but layout

Comment: Post your full logcat showing the NPE stack trace

Comment: what's line 20 in PopUpWifi.java class?
>>> com.safesecuresam.home.PopUpWifi.onCreate(PopUpWifi.java:20) <<<

Comment: TVWifi.setText(value);

Comment: How many layout files do you have? Is it just a typo in the question or is it possible that you have a "pupupwifi.xml" and a "popupwifi.xml"?

Comment: I have only one popupwifi.xml.

Comment: Can it be because i want to call an Activity from a Fragment?

Comment: Debug your application, when calling `popup.putExtra("WiFiID", String.valueOf(name));` Check what name reffers to. This is likely incomplete, a null string, or some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `android:id="@+id/TVWifi"`  instead of using `android:name="@+id/TVWifi"`